# How to install numpy and scipy for python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I used the redhat Linux. I want to install the numpy and scipy for python2.7. I tried to install and do the following activities:

```
1. download the numpy and scipy using wget command
2. extract the tar file using the tar command 
3. when I build using the python setup.py build and when I try the python setup.py commands the error happen as "This is the wrong setup.py file to run"    The setup.py file is found inside the folder.
```

For example:

```
/home/desktop/kk/python setup.py build
```

here inside kk there is the setup.py file.

what is the problem and solution?

Comment: Can you use `python -m pip install mypy scipy`?

Comment: Try  `python setup.py  install

Answer (score 1):

**Easy way:**

1. use pip and execute following commands on your terminal:
   pip install numpy
   pip install scipy
   Note: To install a specific version use "==" as a suffix

   ```
    e.g. `pip install numpy==1.13.3`
   ```
2. use easy_install and execute following commands on your terminal:

   `easy_install numpy`

   `easy_install scipy`

**Bulky Way (Legacy Version)**

Step 1: Download the package from **pypi**(preferably) or any other source.

Step 2: Extract the package on the location where all of your packages are 
        there (*usually it is prefix/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages*). You'll 
        get a file "setup.py" after extraction.

Step 3: Open your terminal and navigate to the location of your "setup.py" 
        file and execute `python setup.py` command.

Answer (score 0):

it's actually better to use [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) which is a great tool managing python packages.
[this is the installation guide](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/)
then you can type:

- pip install numpy
- pip install sicpy